# How can you become a zombie?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

My little boy wants to change to a zombie character and we don't know how to do it.

In the original plants vs. zombies, how do you play as a zombie?

Comment: IIRC, you cant. If it IS possible, it's a closer-to-end-game unlock

Comment: Just to be sure, you're not talking about the 3D game, Garden Warfare, are you?

Answer (score 26):

In the original "wave-defense" game, the primary campaign is to defend against the zombies. However, later in the game you can "practice" as the zombies in a minigame called "[I, Zombie](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/I,_Zombie)".

Additionally, if you play on the Xbox, you can challenge your friends online, which you can choose which side to play on - Plants, or Zombies.

---

In PvZ 2, a similar minigame (or "Brain Buster") to the original's "I, Zombie", called "[Zomboss Test lab](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Brain_Busters#Zomboss_Test_Lab_.C2.A0.28China_only.29)" allows the player to once again, "practice" as the Zombies attacking the garden.

---

In the more recent games, the 3rd person shooter game called "Garden Warfare", you can choose a Plant or a Zombie to play as. Which side you play on is randomized, but it should alternate regularly, giving you an even chance to play on either team.

Comment: +1 for the bundled info, I've only ever played the original on PC and Android. Interesting about the Xbox version though! that sounds like fun :)

Comment: @Robotnik it certainly makes it more interesting. Playing against another player definitely adds another level of difficulty, not knowing what the opponent is thinking!

Comment: @Robotnik Nintendo DS also have [muliplayer](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Versus_Mode). Quite fun, and portable ;)

Answer (score 18):

The only possible way to play as the Zombies is in the [I, Zombie](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/I,_Zombie) minigame:

> I, Zombie is a series of Puzzle Mode levels, in which the player "plants" zombies with sun to destroy cardboard plants and get to the brains at the end of each row. A level is completed when all of the brains have been eaten, but if the player runs out of sun, they will lose.

This minigame (along with most of the other minigames) will be unlocked as you progress through the main story - which you must play as the 'plants' (as the person planting them at least).